# Connected and Locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Im having some trouble with the following:
Let $X=(0,1)$ and $T=\{(0,1-\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N},n\geq 2\} \cup \{X,Ø\}$
I want to prove that (X,T) is:

- **Connected**
  The definition of being connected:
  Let (X,T) be a topological space, then (X,T) is connected if:
  For all open $U,V \subseteq X$ s.t. $X=U\sqcup V$: U=Ø or V=Ø.
- **Locally compact**
  The definition of being locally compact:
  (X,T) is locally compact at $x \in X$ If there is a compact subspace of X that contains a neighborhood of x (and if (X,T) is locally compact at all $x \in X$, then (X,T) is locally compact)
  I Also know that every compact space is locally compact so I was thinking of showing that (X,T) is compact. The definiton of compact:
  Let (X,T) be a topological space. Then (X,T) is compact if every open cover of X has a finite subcover.

  I have already proven that (X,T) is a topological space and I Also know that (X,T) is not $T_1$, but I am a little unsure of where to start with showing (X,T) is connected and locally compact…

Comment: Connectedness: can you find any non-trivial open subset that is closed as well? Just check all non-trivial open sets. Compact: the collection of sets $(1-\frac1{n})$ cover $(0,1)$. Can you find any finite subcollection? Locally compact: are sets of form $(0,c]$ compact? Can they serve as compact neighborhoods, maybe?

Comment: For connectedness, can you see that any two non-trivial open sets are always intersecting?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but I am a little unsure of the method still, since this is the first time Im working with these terms/properties

Answer (score 1):

**Connected:** The space is connected. In fact the space has the much stronger property that **any** two nonempty open sets intersect. ***Prove this part for yourself.*** So we cannot have two nonempty opens $U,V$ with $U \cap V = \varnothing$ and $U \cup V = X$. In fact we cannot have two nonempty opens $U,V$ with $U \cap V = \varnothing$ regardless of the second condition!

**Compactness:**  In this case each $x \in (0,1)$ has $x < 1-\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$. I claim  $(0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$. It should be obvious it contains an open neighborhood of $x$. For compactness suppose $(0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ is covered by some open sets $$\left (0,1-\frac{1}{n_1} \right ),\left (0,1-\frac{1}{n_2} \right )\ldots  .$$ I claim there is a single element of the cover that already covers all of $(0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$. ***Prove this part for yourself.***

Comment: In fact, *any* subset of $(0,1-\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ is compact

Comment: @Milten Oooh that's much nicer.